# Verify authentication - Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want only the authenticated users to modify classes in the database.
For example:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(("anything (I don't know how") => {
     // Something like this
    if (!verify(request.user)) {
        response.error("Not authenticated / Token is invalid");
        return
    }
    // ...
    response.success();
});
```

Do you have any ideas?
Note that this is the first time I'm using Parse.

Comment: If you want to restrict access to modify/create/read a certain class, you should be able to use CLPs. To set these up,  you will probably need to have a dashboard available.  But these will let you specify which roles and users are able to preform what actions on each class.

Comment: @EReid
I've installed parse-dashboard but I cannot find how I can add Roles.

Comment: That's probably best suited for another question.  But you can add a row in the Role class. And should be able to add users in the users relation on that item.  This can also be done programmatically too, which I would probably advise.  To secure a particular class,  you can go to security and add the new role.  I would recommended you take a look at the security section in the parse guides here: https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/

Comment: Thanks, @EReid, CLP solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `verify()` function like this:

```
function verify(user) {
    var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();

    if(!sessionToken)
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    else 
    {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("_Session"));
        return query.first({useMasterKey:false, sessionToken:sessionToken })
            .then(function(validSessionToken){
                //User is signed in, and has a valid token (not expired yet)
                return true;
            })
            .fail(function(){        
                //User doesn't have a valid sessionToken
                return false;
            });

    }
}
```

Idea is to "verify" sessionToken by issuing a query to _Session Class, looking for the _Session Object having the same sessionToken as the Request object, not using the MASTER_KEY.

If sessionToken exists, it will be returned, because it has ACL to be accessed using MASTER_KEY and user having the current sessionToken.

Using a sessionToken in query and not MASTER_KEY, you will never be able to see other sessionTokens except that one.

Comment: Why would you return from a promise ?

Comment: @FrenchFalcon Because I **PROMISED** I will return the result, at some point in future... and I keep my fu**ing promises...

Comment: First, watch your language. Second, you just modified your code.

Comment: @FrenchFalcon First, don't tell me what to do, this is internet, I can language how ever the hell I want. Second, I modified my code, but it is **STILL** returning from a promise... right? Or you are having hard time understanding promises... yeah, you probably do... Also, there is a **GOOD** explanation below the code about the **IDEA** on how to solve the problem - which you probably didn't read, because you were here for the code to copy.

Comment: I was just saying that you were returning from inside the promise but not returning the promise itself, so that wouldn't do anything. Stop acting like a rebel teenager please.

Comment: Yes, and I still am returning from the promise... and I'm also returning the promise... and I am a rebel teenager bro.

Comment: Thats not what you were doing before you modified. Ugh seriously I feel like I’m talking to a wall. SO is not made for that.